# Isn't there a limit on account suspension time?

Tags: discussion

I have found questions detailing changes to automatic review bans being extended beyond 30 days but I always thought the account suspension was anywhere between 1 day and a year (see [here](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/04/06/a-day-in-the-penalty-box/) for Jeff's original announcement).

Then I found a user with the following entry on their user page (changed just the day and time to ensure no chance of inadvertently identifying the person):

`This account is temporarily suspended network-wide. The suspension period ends on Feb dd '25 at h:mm.`

That's a ***five-year*** ban by the looks of it, quite harsh but, of course,  I don't know whether it was deserved or not.

Now I'm having a hard time envisioning what could cause a ban that long but *not* cause total account deletion but my question is this: *is* there a limit on suspension time or will it just get longer and longer as an individual doesn't adjust their behaviour?

---

Don't worry, I'm not planning any actions that would *test* this limit for myself :-)

And it may even be worse than I first thought - the user hasn't posted anything since '16 so it may well have been a nine-year suspension.

Comment: Related: [Why not perma-ban instead of suspend an account for 275 years?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/319634/289905).

Comment: Ah, didn't think to look on the SE meta site, I just couldn't find anything here on the SO one.

Comment: I remember a moderator saying that the limit is 9999 years, but I'm not sure. I don't have a source for it.

Comment: Limit for mods = 1yr; Limit for Staff = None;

Comment: @10Rep: possibly restricted by field size in the DB then. Of course, that's the same shoddy thinking that gave us the Y2K issue. What if, at some point in the future, we *want* to suspend someone for more than ten millennia? :-)

Comment: @paxdiablo my thinking is that if Methuselah and / or Beelzebub can’t figure out how to interact with the community in a few millennia then the world has gone to pot anyway and they are welcome to their SO account.. ;-)

Comment: Side note: a *network-wide* suspension is already proof of staff involvement. Us regular moderators can only suspend someone here on this site, not across all sites in one go.

Comment: And finally, Tim’s answer to [this Meta.SE question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/211217/how-long-can-a-temporary-suspension-be) is pretty much the authoritative treatise on the subject. Any non-network-wide suspensions that are still in place on Stack Overflow date back to 2013 at the latest.

Comment: "..still in place on Stack Overflow date back to 2013.." I do not understand this. Beyond some initial time, there's no point in cooling off for more years. I mean does anyone really cool more off in two years than in one?

Comment: One limit [mentioned previously is 274 years](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/284807/account-temporarily-suspended-network-wide-for-the-next-10-years-and-cannot#comment1059459_284807). (100,000 days = approx. 274 years. (Or 99,999 days?)) There may be a difference between chat and account suspension.